# Can SneakerNet Consider As Network?

Tags: network, terminology

As the title of the question, is that sneakernet can consider as a network？

Or a network is the devices must be connected via cable or wireless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can, it uses media (the ground) to transport packetized data (human 'frames' carrying 'packets' (physical data drives like flash or hard drives or even paper) of information to deliver data from a sender to a receiver, etc.